# Facebook Feed Dialog Parameters vs. Open Graph Meta Tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Do the Open Graph meta tags override the corresponding parameter values passed in [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)?

I have a page where I have an `og:description` tag (I want it to be used by the like button). I have a share button which triggers a share dialog using FB.ui.
Coffeescript Code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: Selfstarter.baseUrl(),
    caption: caption,
    name: 'Healthfundit',
    description: 'Some Description',
    actions: [{name:'Help Fund It!', link: Selfstarter.baseUrl() + "/preorder/checkout"  }]
    source: source
    }, (response) ->);
```

When I test the share button, the description that is displayed is the one I specified in the `og:description` tag.

Comment: _“Do the Open Graph meta tags override the corresponding parameter values passed in FB.ui?”_ – no, the other way around. If that’s not working for you, then most likely there’s an error in your code. Have you tried with the plain JS code as shown in the docs?

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I had multiple click event handlers getting attached to the button. One of them was passing the same value that was set in og:description. I removed the incorrect event handler. Works as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: You can post your comment as answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do the Open Graph meta tags override the corresponding parameter values passed in FB.ui?

No, the other way around.

If that’s not working for you, then most likely there’s an error in your code. *[As we figured out, that was it.]*